# GAE tutorial - browsing 'Localhost:8080' gives me server error?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the Google App Engine GUI. Not sure what I'm doing wrong since I'm following Google's lead on this one. In the GUI, the app is running on admin port 8000 and listening in on port 8080. When I go to localhost:8080, I get a 'Server Error' in Chrome. Is this a firewall problem or a GAE problem?

helloudacity.py

```
 import webapp2

 class mainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

      def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, Udacity!')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
], debug=true)
```

app.yaml

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
 - url: /.*
   script: helloudacity.application
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to capitalize mainPage in your routes and debug=true to True. If you look at error console most of the errors should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `debug=true` to `debug=True`.

The booleans on Python are `True` or `False`.

[Google´s sample](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) is right.